# get attribute in backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

i have a model extend Backbone.Model and have an array attribute named 'labels', by default labels is empty, but later on will filled with data in second function and used in third function, however I had problem to access the 'labels', here is my code

```
  class GroupTreatmentGraphModel extends Backbone.Model

    initialize: () ->

    defaults:
      type : 'bar'
      labels: []    
      yFormatter: (y) -> y + ' counts'
      xFormatter:(x) ->  
        for p,q of labels   <-- get error msg: ReferenceError: labels is not defined
          console.log "lp=#{p}, lq=#{q}"
        labels[parseInt(x)]

    setData: (cid, data) ->
      tmp=@get('labels')
      console.log "1. get series, label.length="+tmp.length        <-- works fine here
      series = _.find @get('series'), (item) -> item  .cid == cid
      series.setData(data)

      countDone = _.countBy @get('series'), (item) -> if item.get('data')? then 'done' else 'notdone'
      if countDone.done == @get('series').length
        @setLabels(data)      
        @set('done', true)

    setLabels: (data) ->
        lbl = []
        for k,v of data
          if typeof(v.z) isnt "undefined" <-- for example: k=0, v.x=0, v.z='hell..o,worm!'
            lbl[parseInt(v.x)] = v.z

        @set('labels', lbl)
        tmp = @get('labels') 
        console.log "label length="+ tmp.length  <-- works fine here

    sync: () ->
      callback = (err, response, cid) =>
        console.log err if err
        @setData(cid, response) if response

      series = @get('series')
      if series
        _.each series, (singleSeries) ->
          $.ajax
            cache: false
            type: 'GET'
            url: singleSeries.get('uri')
            dataType: 'json'
            error: (jqxhr) ->
              callback jqxhr, null, singleSeries.cid
            success: (response) ->
              callback null, response, singleSeries.cid

  return GroupTreatmentGraphModel
```

and my app code is:

```
graph = new GroupTreatmentGraphModel
  position: 2
  title: 'SM Total vs Success By Group-Treatment'
  series: [
    new SeriesData
      name: 'gtt'
      color: 'steelblue'
      uri: '/api/gtt'
    new SeriesData
      name: 'gts'
      color: 'lightblue'
      uri: '/api/gts'  
  ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want `yFormatter` and `xFormatter` in `defaults` at all. `defaults` is intended to supply default values for model attributes and attributes are meant to come from a JSON data source, JSON is for plain-ish data and doesn't support functions so putting functions into `defaults` is a strange thing to do.

Instead, make them methods on the model:

```
class GroupTreatmentGraphModel extends Backbone.Model

  initialize: () ->

  defaults: ->
    type : 'bar'
    labels: { }

  yFormatter: (y) -> "#{y} counts"
  xFormatter: (x) ->  
    labels = @get('labels')
    for p,q of labels
      console.log "lp=#{p}, lq=#{q}"
    labels[parseInt(x)]

  #...
```

Notice a couple other changes:

1. You have mutable date in your `defaults` so you should use a function to ensure that you don't accidentally share references. The values in `defaults` are shallow copied straight into models so if you have an array or object in `defaults`, you can end up with exactly the same array or object being shared by several models.
2. You're saying `for p,q of labels` so your `labels` property is presumably an object rather than an array. Hence the `labels: { }` in the `defaults function. OTOH you're saying`labels[parseInt(x)]`so maybe`labels`is supposed to be an array and your loop is supposed to be`for e, i in labels` instead.
3. I switched to string interpolation in `yFormatter`, many find this clearer than a bunch of quotes and `+` signs.
4. Since `labels` is a model attribute, `xFormatter` accesses it as `@get('labels')`.